# CSS Animation Starting From Middle

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a pretty simple animation that has borders that I created animate in width, in height, and then the center fades in.

The issue I'm having is I can't figure out how to animate from the center, rather than left to right (for the top  and bottom borders) and top to bottom (for the side borders).

Is there any simple way to get the animation to happen from the middle?

Example of the code for the top and bottom animation:

```
@keyframes tb {                                                             
  0% {width: 0;}
  100% {width: 800px}
}
```

[JSFiddle of the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/9gL72qqr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the `left` and `top`, too. For the horizontal bars, set the property `left` to 400px (50%) on the first keyframe, and to 0px on the last keyframe. Same goes for the vertical bars. Here is your fixed example:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700);
html{
  background: black;
}
#holder{
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#follower {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  animation: main 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: main 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes main {                            
  0% {opacity: 0}
  50% {opacity: 0}
  100%{opacity: 1} 
}
@-webkit-keyframes main {                            
  0% {opacity: 0}
  50% {opacity: 0} 
  100%{opacity: 1}
}

#t, #b {
  width: 800px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  animation: tb .5s 1 ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: tb .5s 1 ease-out;
}

#t {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#b{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#r, #l {
  width: 2px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  animation: rl 1s 1 ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: rl 1s 1 ease-out;
}

#r{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#l {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes tb {                            
  0% {
      width: 0;
      left: 400px;
  }
  100% {
      width: 800px
      left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rl {                            
  0% {height: 0}
  50% {
      height: 0;
      top: 55px;
  }
  100% {
      height: 110px;
      top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="t"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="r"></div>
  <div id="l"></div>
  <div id="follower">
    Super Long Text Goest Here!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, wow - I was pretty close with what I tried, but just a little different.  I'm actually not sure why it didn't work similarly, perhaps I screwed up syntax.  Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @DRBC Np :) If the answer did solve your problem, please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with your timing, and make it start at right point in your animation... using an animation-delay.

E.g.

```
@keyframes makeFatter {                                                             
  0% {width: 0;}
  100% {width: 800px}
}

#makeMeFat {
  animation-name: makeFatter;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: -2.5s;  /* Makes it start at 50% of your animation, i.e. width: 400px */
  /* blah blah... rest of the CSS code */
}
```